# OBIEE - Is it possible to have a sub query in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

When I add the following line, I get an error:
`COUNT(select "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker"."Person Number" FROM "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time" where "Worker"."Person Number" > 1000)`

What I want to do is add a new column and have a COUNT for the number of employees with a person number > than 1000.

===================

```
SELECT 
   0 s_0,
   "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker"."Employee First Name" s_1,
   "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker"."Person ID" s_2,
   "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker"."Person Number" s_3,
   "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker"."Person Start Date" s_4,
   "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker"."Termination Date" s_5,
   DESCRIPTOR_IDOF("Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker"."Worker Category") s_6,
   "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker Assignment"."Head Count" s_7,
    COUNT(select "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker"."Person Number" FROM "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time" where "Worker"."Person Number" > 1000) s_8

FROM "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"
```

The error I get with Over()

```
Error generating view. Error getting cursor in GenerateHead
  Error Details
Error Codes: OAMP2OPY:OPR4ONWY:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:OI2DL65P:OI2DL65P
Odbc driver returned an error (SQLExecDirectW).
State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 43113. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 27002. [nQSError: 27002] Near <(>: Syntax error (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 26012. [nQSError: 26012] . (HY000)
SQL Issued: {call NQSGetQueryColumnInfo('SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker"."Person Number" > 1000 THEN 1 END) OVER() FROM "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"')}
SQL Issued: SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker"."Person Number" > 1000 THEN 1 END) OVER() FROM "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` window function with a `CASE` expression:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker"."Person Number" > 1000 THEN 1 END) OVER() s_8
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to remove the OVER() at the end as it gives me an error. Also this is only showing when the current row employee has a person number > 1000, can I change this so it shows on every row, regardless of the current row person number?

Comment: OVER() is part of the syntax of the analytic function COUNT(): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174 If you use as it is in the code it should be ok. What is the message?

Comment: OVER() at the end is not wrong. This is the way to get the column that you want. If you get an error then you don't use it correctly, or the code in your question is not your actual code. See a simplified demo of how to use it in Oracle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3818ab82c1c029ded7fb92f334f663b0

Comment: Shouldn't the FROM clause be: `FROM "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"."Worker"`?

Comment: If Worker is an attribute then what is "Person Number"? Isn't "Person Number" a column in a table/view?

Comment: Sorry you are correct. Person Number is a column and Worker is the folder and "Workforce Management - Worker Assignment Real Time"  is the subject area.

Comment: *folder* and *subject area* are not SQL terms. My code is SQL code for Oracle.